# LyX 2.1.1 fails to compile knitr-manual.lyx

Tags: r, knitr, pdflatex, lyx

LyX 2.1.1 fails to compile [knitr-manual.lyx](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-manual.lyx) and [knitr-graphics.lyx](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/inst/examples/knitr-graphics.lyx) as well (currently installed knitr version 1.6).

The error does not say much (i.e. `LyX: Cannot convert file` -- see screenshot).  Could it be related to file-permission bits?  How should I go about it?

[image]

Maybe of interest,

```
Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
```

**Update**

From the message pane, there is indeed an *Error* line:

```
12:28:16.235: Quitting from lines 93-93 (/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.gwIlgToM2017/lyx_tmpbuf1/knitr-graphics.Rnw) 
12:28:16.238: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'Cairo'
12:28:16.241: Calls: knit ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
12:28:16.244: 
12:28:16.247: Execution halted
```

No cairo?  What does this mean in the contect of knitr and LyX/LaTeX?

Comment: did you activate the knitr module ? http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/lyx/

Comment: We've seen problems like these on Windows due to something strange happening with the path. Can you start from the terminal and see if it gives any extra debug information? I don't know how to do that on Windows. There might also be information in view > messages.

Comment: @Henk All of the examples, in the knitr- github reposiroty, compile just fine. Except for the manual and the graphics.

Comment: @scottkosty I work with Funtoo-Linux. I didn't see anything interesting in the message pane. Will re-check.

Comment: @scottkosty Indeed, found something after being more careful. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R was missing the "Cairo" package. And the "tikzDevice" package as well. Installing those two, via

```
install.packages("Cairo", dep = TRUE)
install.packages("tikzDevice", dep = TRUE)
```

resolved the issues. At least, there is no compilation error related to missing packages anymore.

Comment: You are free to accept your own answer. `dep = TRUE` is probably not necessary, though.

Comment: In case of such kind of problems, always checking for missing packages is, I guess, a must-do. I also needed to install *rggobi* as the *graphics* example wouldn't compile as well.

Comment: @Yihui Will accept after some time -- there is a period before which one cannot accept an (his own) answer. knitr is just Excellent work :-)